# How can i clone an image in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, cross-browser, copy, clone

I'm  trying to clone an image in javascript, bud without loading a new one.
Normally new browsers will load an image once and there are several ways to use that image again.
The problem is that when I test it in IE 6 the image will request a new image from the server.

Anyone how has some info on how to do this in older browsers?

3 methods that not work:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Image Cloning</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        sourceImage = new Image();
        sourceImage.src = "myImage.png";

        function cloneImageA () {
            imageA = new Image();
            imageA.src = sourceImage.src;
            document.getElementById("content").appendChild(imageA);
        }

        function cloneImageB () {
            imageB =  sourceImage.cloneNode(true);
            document.getElementById("content").appendChild(imageB);
        }

        function cloneImageC()
        {
            var HTML = '<img src="' + sourceImage.src + '" alt="" />';
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += HTML;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="controle">
        <button onclick="cloneImageA();">Clone method A</button>
        <button onclick="cloneImageB();">Clone method B</button>
        <button onclick="cloneImageC();">Clone method C</button>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        Images:<br>
    </div>
</body>
```

### Solution

Added cache-headers server-side with a simple .htaccess file in the directory of the image(s):
/img/.htaccess

```
Header unset Pragma
Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=3600, must-revalidate"
```

**All of the above javascript method's will use the image loaded if the cache-headers are set.**

Comment: Why in the world are you testing in IE 6?

Comment: @Iwburk : wild guess, don't shoot me : it's a prerequisite.

Comment: @lwburk because it would help to get server requests down.
People are still using older browsers no matter what.

Comment: You could try discouraging people to use IE6 by showing some box on the start page advising them to upgrade. Something like: "*this site may not work as expected in your browser. Please upgrade to ... etc.*"

Comment: @Kooilnc : Good point, I will when there is no other solution

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Afaik the default browser behavior is to cache images. So something like this should work the way you want:

```
 var sourceImage = document.createElement('img'),
     imgContainer = document.getElementById("content");
 sourceImage.src = "[some img url]";
 imgContainer.appendChild(sourceImage);

 function cloneImg(){
     imgContainer.appendChild(sourceImage.cloneNode(true));
 }
```

It's all pretty sop, so it should run in IE6 too (I don't have it, so can't test that). 
[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/4erdQ/)

Furthermore, you may want to check the cache setting of your IE6 browser. I remember from the not so good old days with IE<8 that I sometimes reverted to setting the cache to refresh "every time you load the page" (or someting like that).

Comment: Its the same method as by `cloneImageA()` function.
Cache settings are at automatic, bud I will try to make some server-side changes related to it.

Comment: You meant `cloneImageB` I suppose? And yes, overseen that. If you control the server, cache headers may indeed also have something to do with it.

Comment: Yes, `cloneImageB()`. I added a simple .htaccess file with the following commands:
`Header unset Pragma` And 
`Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=3600, must-revalidate"` 

Thats the solution, works like charm also in IE6.

Answer (score 2):

javascript has provisions for this build in.
here is code modified from Danny Goodman's Javascript Bible 2nd Ed p.498,500 for cacheing/preloading an image,

```
<img src='/images/someotherimage1.png' id='img1'>
<img src='/images/someotherimage2.png' id='img2'>
<img src='/images/someotherimage3.png' id='img3'>
<script type="text/javascript">
function assignall(numImages, x, y) {
    var img = new Image(x, y);
    img.src = '/images/someimage.png';
    var x;
    for (x=1; x <= numImages; x++) {
        document.getElementById('img'+x).src = img.src;
    }
}

assignall(3); //do it.
</script>
```

you can always use an array if you have a number of images to work with.

```
var img = new Array();
function initallimages(numImages, x, y) {
    var x;
    for (x=1; x <= numImages; x++) {
        img['img' + x] = new Image(x,y);
        img['img' + x].src = '/images/someimage.png';
    }
 }
 function assignallimages(numImages) {
    var x;
    for (x=1; x <= numImages; x++) {
        document.getElementById('img' + x).src = img['img'+x]['img' + x].src;
    }
}

initallimages(3, 320, 240);
assignallimages(3);
```

Comment: Found the solution server-sided, I will still test this. Thank you for the response!

Comment: Its does clone an image, bud when used with events they will load the image again.
 Tested it a few times bud i can't load the cached image and reuse it (for example) on each mouse click.
Got any tips for me on that? Thank you for your time anyway