# How to use a same image multiple times by loading it only once when I need different id for every element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a newbie to programming and web developing. The project I am doing is only for practice, if my approach seems ameteur to you, please suggest any better options.

I am trying to develop a parking lot booking system. And in the UI, I want to show all the empty/filled slots (like it is while booking movies or bus tickets).

I couldn't find a top view icon of a car, so I thought of using an image instead of icon.

But as of the image, if I use say 50 images on a single page, the page will get very heavy.

But one important thing is that I need all the elements as seperate entities, only then I will be able to book them with their id(unique address). So I want 50 different divs with seperate distinct ids but want to use only one image for all the slots, or a maximum of 2 different images(keeping the directions in mind).

[how to display same image multiple times using same image in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366555/how-to-display-same-image-multiple-times-using-same-image-in-javascript)

I went through this answer, and found a piece of code that might be useful:

```
var imgSrc = 'http://lorempixel.com/100/100';

function generateImage() {
  var img = document.createElement('img')
  img.src = imgSrc;

  return img;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
  document.body.appendChild(generateImage());
}
```

While I can make use of a function and a loop in javascript to create as many copies of one image, I don't know how to alot them to the different div tags with distinct ids.

Comment: You may be fundamentally misunderstanding how a browser goes about this - every time you use the same URL for an image, the browser will reuse the image it first loaded, so you "reuse" the image by simply pointing to the same URL from each `<img>` element.

Answer (score 0):

use a function :)

```
const addMessage = (element, msg, cls) => {
    const patt = new RegExp("<");
    const messageElement = document.createElement("div");
    if (patt.test(msg)) {
        messageElement.innerHTML = msg
    } else messageElement.textContent = msg;
    if (cls) messageElement.classList.add(cls);
    element.appendChild(messageElement);
}
const imgPath = "/somepath";
const body = document.querySelector("body");
addMessage(body, `<img src=${imgPath} class="whatever">`, "img1"); //creates new divs with classes. the 3rd arg is optional
```

Answer (score 0):

the best approach for this is the client side already receiving all this content as a string but as it made clear that it is for study I deduce that it is not the intention to use back end to solve this problem

```
let allContent = '';

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
  allContent += `<div class="wrapper-image"><img src="/path"></div>`
}

document.getElementById('idWrapper').innerHTML = allContent;
```

speaking in performace the browser will only download the image once, so you can use it as many times as you like, which is disruptive to the changes you make in the DOM (remove, add or edit a content)
In my example you create all the content to be displayed on the page and then add it in a single time, it is not too bad if it is performace but the ideal is to do it on the back side

in the `DIV` you can put an image address of a variable to do some logical type this:

```
    let allContent = '';
    let imgOne = '/oneimg';
    let imgOne = '/twoImg';

    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
        if(i>10){
            allContent += `<div class="wrapper-image"><img src="${imgOne}"></div>`
        }else {
            allContent += `<div class="wrapper-image"><img src="${twoImg}"></div>`
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('idWrapper').innerHTML = allContent;
```

Comment: Thanks @TheDev 
You said that this issue can be solved on back-end. Look, I am using javaScript for developing the interface, and then I'll use php and sql to create the database and all the internal working of the system. And for clarification, I have just started learning php and sql, so I don't know much functionalities of php and sql and their connectivity.

But my plan was to use front-end to deliver all the visuals of the system, and I am gonna use back-end only for internal working of the system.

Comment: compiling the html to the client side is part of the internal service, the logic that you must apply is, when entering a determinate directory php does all this logic (this loop and this iteration) and then sends the client the HTML already ready to be rendered, with the basic concepts of php you can do this, as easy as with javascript, I do not teach you here because it fades from the focus of the question but it is very easy