# Clone image objects and append

Tags: javascript, append

I have one image variable, which i want to append to 3 different divs. Ive tried adding .clonenode(true) to the end of the object but that did not work. what keeps happening is it goes to the div the last append statement called it to, since there is only one variable. I am trying to avoid making more than one variables, since this is only a smaller scale version of my code.

```
const div1 = document.querySelector('div1');
const div2 = document.querySelector('div2');
const div3 = document.querySelector('div3');
const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'foo.png';
img.style.width = '32px';

function append(){
    div1.appendChild(img);
    div2.appendChild(img);
    div3.appendChild(img);
}
```

Comment: Did you check if image path is correct??

Comment: Check below URL to clone image in JavaScript.  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694986/how-can-i-clone-an-image-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried adding .clonenode(true) to the end of the object but that did not work.

What object?

Try using it on `img` in every `appendChild()` call. That is where you need a clone returned.

```
const div1 = document.querySelector('div1');
const div2 = document.querySelector('div2');
const div3 = document.querySelector('div3');
const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'foo.png';
img.style.width = '32px';

function append(){
  div1.appendChild(img.cloneNode(true));
  div2.appendChild(img.cloneNode(true));
  div3.appendChild(img.cloneNode(true));
}
```